# Permission denied during review build

Tags: appcenter

I wanted to publish an application I made, but the build process always fails after dpkg-buildchecks. In particular the permission for /usr/bin/fakeroot is denied.

I reread the how-to multiple times, but I'm failing to see what I did wrong. Can anyone suggest what I have to change so the build can run?

For reference [the project issue](https://github.com/treagod/spectator/issues/6)